# DAX filter column string values being shown in UI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am displaying values from a specific column in a table, say TableP.

This column has some invalid data that I want to filter out.

Using a DAX measure,

```
Measure = IF ( 'TableP'[columnValue] <> "error@error.com", 'TableP'[columnValue]  )
```

So with the above code, I am getting an error of

```
A single value cannot be determined.
```

So clearly wrong approach. Would appreciate some guidance on best practices :)

Is this the best way to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to filter the records from your data source in data cleaning step in using Power Query editor. But if it is a requirement and you can not perform that, you can create your measure as below-

```
Measure  = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(TableP[your_measure_column]),
    NOT (TableP[columnValue] IN{"error@error.com", "error2@error.com"})
)
```

Here is another option you can try your luck with-

```
Measure  = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(TableP[your_measure_column]),
    FILTER(
        TableP,
        NOT(TableP[columnValue] IN{"error@error.com", "error2@error.com"})
    )
)
```

And.... another option :)

```
Measure  = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(TableP[your_measure_column]),
    NOT CONTAINSROW(
        {"error@error.com", "error2@error.com"},
        TableP[columnValue]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Not returning a sum but individual values in a table visual, let  me try this solution

Comment: You are most welcome @MichaelHolborn. Added another option for your reference.